# Unmasking not found errors and see their real exceptions in Plone

Tags: plone, zope

The following is from Zope's BaseRequest.py:

```
            # traverseName() might raise ZTK's NotFound
            except (KeyError, AttributeError, ztkNotFound):

                if response.debug_mode:
                    return response.debugError(
                        "Cannot locate object at: %s" % URL)
                else:
                    return response.notFoundError(URL)
```

It translate various exceptions to not found page. This is very bad for the site developers, who don't know what actually goes wrong on the site.

How one does disable this mechanism (there is clearly response.debug_mode), so that you would see real exceptions

- When Plone runs in debug mode
- In unit tests and functional tests
- When Plone runs in production mode (e.g temporarily to see why some URL *really* fails)

Comment: Since you already found the code in question, you should already see that there is no such switch. Why not file a feature request for Zope?

Comment: With ZCML wiring, monkey-patching and such, you never know if the trigger is hidden somewhere :) FR then it shall be.

Comment: KeyError and AttributeError can happen on traversal--that's why it's treated as a 404. If you're worried about these errors getting swallowed, you should handle them in your custom code.

Comment: Often simple cause is that you have missing variable in view or template code and it gets later translated to 404. I almost consider this as a bug, since it makes debugging difficult and impossible for new developers who are not aware of this Zope feature.

Comment: Better ask the Python devs to switch of the @property exception-becomes-AttributeError feature too, then. :-P